# Passing a name of named optional argument to a method in C#

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, named-parameters

I was wondering if I can do something like this, that is, pass a name of a named optional parameter to use it in a method call. I'm using a method from a library, which has like 50 optional named parameters (they only change a value of a permission, not really important for the context).

Is there a way to pass a parameter name? I wouldn't have to copy paste pretty much the same method just with a different parameter used at the end just to change a different permission

```cs
void Main()
{
  Test("first", "Hello");
  Test("third", "World");
}

void Test(string option, string value)
{
  // Do something
  TestHelper(option:value);
}

void TestHelper(string? first = null, string? second = null, string? third = null)
{
  // Do something
  return;
}
```

Thanks for any replies :)

Comment: I think you would need to use the Reflection API to do something like this; it's not supported directly in the language or runtime.

Comment: Reflection, that's the exact thing I needed and didn't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "option" names are passed "dynamically" you can use some reflection (otherwise there is not much sense in `Test` method because `TestHelper(first: "Hello")` just works and is better/safe option):

```cs
class Helper
{
    public void Test(string option, string value)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(Helper).GetMethod(nameof(TestHelper));
        var parameterInfos = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        // todo - add runtime error for the case of invalid parameter name passed.
        methodInfo.Invoke(this, parameterInfos.Select(p => p.Name == option ? value : null).ToArray());
    }

    public void TestHelper(string? first = null, string? second = null, string? third = null)
    {
        // Do something
        return;
    }
}
```

Note that in general case reflection is quite costly so if the method is called quite often during the application lifetime you should consider "caching" it for example by using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) or just generating the method body using [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).